# jQuery check two fields in one remote, mysql one table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below is my code;

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var fieldA = $('#fieldA').attr('value');
var fieldB = $('#fieldB').attr('value');

    $('#simpleForm').validate({

    errorLabelContainer: "#error_message_box",
    wrapper: "li",

        rules: {                
            firstname: "required",
            fieldA: "required",
            fieldB: {
                                    required: true,
                remote: "chk.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "fieldA=" + fieldA + "fieldB=" + fieldB
                    }
        },
        messages: {                
            firstname: "Please enter your first name.",
                            fieldA: "Please enter field A.",
            fieldB: {
                                    required: "Please enter field B.",
                remote: "Field B already exist."
                                    }               
        }

    });

});
```

I can't check if field A and field B both exist inside MySQL same table.

In PHP file only can only get fieldA, can't get fieldB.

Comment: data: "fieldA=" + fieldA + "fieldB=" + fieldB <- what is expected here? shouldn't you use a JSON object instead?

Answer (score 0):

It should be -

```
data: "fieldA=" + fieldA + "&fieldB=" + fieldB
```

not

```
data: "fieldA=" + fieldA + "fieldB=" + fieldB
```

I prefer to use -

```
data : {
    fieldA: fieldA,
    fieldB: fieldB
}
```

because its more easier to build and understand, although not sure if validate supports this format, but `$.ajax` does support it

Comment: i had upload whole script to [basic links](http://aloedelivery.com/stackoverflow/)

Comment: can view the full source script

Comment: chk.php script very simple, can view at [basic links](http://aloedelivery.com/stackoverflow/chk.html)

Comment: You are sending `POST` but you are using `$_GET`, thats never gonna work. use `$_POST` instead

Comment: hi Mahmud, i try change $_GET to $_POST still the same, even required field not function at all.